# Is it possible to attach textures as render target to the default framebuffer?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Is it possible to attach textures as render target to the default framebuffer?

I.e.

```
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    GLenum bufs[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
    glDrawBuffers(2, bufs);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, sceneTexture, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, postProcessingStuffTexture, 0);
    // Draw something
```

Also why does rendering to texture happen without anit-aliasing? Was pretty happy with my cheap 5xRCSAA or what it was.

Comment: I can't make it work. As soon as I use the default FBO to attach textures to I get garbled results. Furthermore, the result does never change. This tells me OGL actively refuses drawing to the attached texture. https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture.xml says near the bottom "GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if zero is bound to target" but there is no explanation as to why and the statement itself is not sufficiently thorough.

Comment: No, you cannot attach a texture to the default framebuffer object because such a thing does not exist. The window system API manages the default framebuffer, the best you can do in this respect is get something like a WGL/GLX pbuffer.

Comment: @ypnos: Please spread no misinformation. The default framebuffer is associated with the system provided render targets and textures can not be bound to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to attach textures as render target to the default framebuffer?

No.

> Also why does rendering to texture happen without anit-aliasing?

Because antialiasing requires a multisample render target. Regular textures are not multisampled. But there are multisample textures which for that purpose. You can create a multisample texture object using [glTexStorage2DMultisample](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexStorage2DMultisample.xhtml) or [glTexImage2DMultisample](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2DMultisample.xhtml).

Comment: What methods does a multisample texture use (supersample, multisample?); how is a sample distribution algorithm determined (if supersampling)? I imagine any kind of extra sampling does heavy changes at the rasterizer stage. To my knowing there is no way to customize that part of GL, so the driver should be dictating any AA methods, no?

Comment: @Zyl: The OpenGL specification is deliberately unspecific about the actual multisampling method used. But this is not very much different from regular multisampled window pixelformats. What you set is the minimum number of samples to have per pixel, and the driver will then choose the closest, larger number supported. There *are* vendor specific extensions to fine tune multisampling, though. Have a look at them: OpenGL extensions are documented at http://opengl.org/registry look for anything with "multisample" in the name; things not named `_ARB_` or `_EXT_` are vendor specific.